# install elastic search in docker

Tags: docker, elasticsearch

I used these two commands in cmd:

```
docker pull elasticsearch
```

show error:

```
Using default tag: latest
Error response from daemon: manifest for elasticsearch:latest not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown
```

and this command with several different versions:

```
docker pull docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.9.0
```

show error:

```
Error response from daemon: Get https://docker.elastic.co/v2/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/manifests/7.9.0: Get https://docker-auth.elastic.co/auth?scope=repository%3Aelasticsearch%2Felasticsearch%3Apull&service=token-service: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

**how to resolve this problem?**
please guide me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at your error message, while pulling the docker image, it seems that your network is blocking you to access the public docker repo to fetch the image.

> request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout
> exceeded while awaiting headers)

By any chance are you behind a VPN or firewall or having some restricition on public network/docker registry access?

Answer (score 16):

latest version of elastic search does not work out of the box

https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-docker/issues/215

so, use specific version to install

```
docker pull docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.11.1
```

Comment: had the same issue, specifying the version to install worked for me

Comment: To see the latest available version you can go to https://hub.docker.com/_/elasticsearch/tags

Answer (score 4):

Use this command to specify the version you want:

```
docker run elasticsearch:{version} -d
```

For example:

```
docker run elasticsearch:8.4.3 -d
```

Answer (score 1):

Can other images be pulled?
Have you made any modifications to the docker default registry like adding new local registries to this file

```
/etc/containers/registries.conf
```

https://www.docker.com/blog/how-to-use-your-own-registry/

and also please check with the port rules for port **5000**.

Answer (score 1):

1. check your firewall, might likely be the culprit.
2. had the same issue running a compose file trying to pull image from `image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:${VERSION}` i modified it to `image: elasticsearch:${VERSION}` and it worked. i.e. removing the docker.elastic.co/elastisearch part of the original url